# how to register a sip user using MYSQL in asterisk?

Tags: mysql, asterisk

I want to register a sip user dynamically by verifying the credentials specified in database which I have connected to ?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what you're trying to do?  "Registration" requires configuration at both the SIP server and client.

Comment: Before registering the user must be checked in a table and if the user exists he would be able to register. @eggyal

Comment: Make asterisk use mysql DB for the user instead of referring to sip.conf @eggyal

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read upon the extconfig.conf file, used especially for this:

```
;
; Static and realtime external configuration
; engine configuration
;
; See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Realtime+Database+Configuration
; for basic table formatting information.
;
[settings]
;
; Static configuration files:
;
; file.conf => driver,database[,table[,priority]]
;
; maps a particular configuration file to the given
; database driver, database and table (or uses the
; name of the file as the table if not specified)
;
;uncomment to load queues.conf via the odbc engine.
;
;queues.conf => odbc,asterisk,ast_config
;extensions.conf => sqlite,asterisk,ast_config
```

Regards, Mirko

Comment: Make asterisk use mysql DB for the user instead of referring to sip.conf @muthuGanapathy

Comment: @tkrKarthikeyan how to make asterisk to refer `DB` instead of `sip.conf`

Comment: well, I think I have explained how to :D

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make use of **Asterisk Realtime Architecture** (ARA), which enables you to store the configuration files (that would normally be found in /etc/asterisk) and their configuration options in a database table.

The following [link](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/I_section12_tt1465.html) clearly describes creation of databases to replace sip.conf with database table.

You will also need to setup the odbc connector for asterisk. You can find more information about installing mysql and its odbc connector in the following [link](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/installing_configuring_odbc.html).